# Insert into a column using group by value of another column of the same table

Tags: mysql, sql

```
id name count
------------
1  abc
2  xyz
3  xyz
4  xyz
```

The following query "select count(name) from temp group by name;" gives me:

```
count(name)
--------
1
3
```

I want this result to be updated to the column 'count'. To be precise I want my table to look like :

```
id name count
------------
1  abc   1
2  xyz   3
3  xyz   3
4  xyz   3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get those values with a COUNT / GROUP BY. You can do an UPDATE statement which joins your table with the sub query:-

```
UPDATE temp a
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT name, COUNT(*) AS name_count
  FROM temp
  GROUP BY name
  ) b
  ON a.name = b.name
SET a.name_count = b.name_count;
```